# Ajax error inside onclick event for hyperlink in Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, click

I have a hyperlink that users click to download a file, and I need to keep track of the download. I used jQuery onClick event to capture user clicks, and use ajax to call a function that tracks the download. After the function succeeds, it echos out a success message. In Firebug, the ajax call ends in error (red), but there is no status, and no response text. I don't have this problem in Chrome.

```
$(".docMainActions a.fdownload").on("click", function(e){
    var docId = $(this).attr("id");
    var post_url = 'index.php?option=com_mycomp&type=repository&tmpl=raw&task=trackdownloadfile&docId='+docId;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: post_url,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('tracked correctly');
        }
    });
});
```

I am using JQuery 1.10. I don't understand why I am having this issue in Firefox. Any suggestions is most appreciated.

Comment: where the user will be clicking ? if it is an href you may have to use prevent default. do this works fine in chrome ?

Comment: What error firebug returns?

Comment: Zod, the user clicks on a hyperlink. The code works as expected on Chrome and IE. There is no error returned from Firebug. I see the ajax request in the Console tab is highlighted red but no error messages in the sub tabs.

Comment: add an `error` key with a function to see if it fires:

`$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: post_url,
        success: function(msg) {
            alert('tracked correctly');
        }
        error: function(msg) {
            alert('error: '+msg);
        }
    });`

Comment: Thanks Adriel. Your suggestion helped me find the error status. My problem was having ajax call when clicking a link. I needed to use preventDefault in my function.